# SELECT dentro de variável em PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, stored-procedures

Não estou conseguindo colocar o resultado de um `select` dentro de uma variável.

Quero acrescentar a coluna `turno` dentro do meu `WHERE`. O problema é que recebo o valor de `@turnos` nos 3 seguintes formatos:

> 1 - `'A'`
>
> 2 - `'A','B'`
>
> 3 - `'A','B','C'`

### Situação atual

```
set @tjt = (select sum(duracao) from tabela where fabrica = @fabrica)
```

### Situação desejada (com erro)

```
set @tjt= (select sum(duracao) from tabela where fabrica = @fabrica and turno IN (@turnos))
```

Já vi que `turno IN (@turnos)` não funciona, e por isso tentei colocar o `select` todo entre aspas concatenando as variáveis da seguinte maneira:

```
@query = '(select sum(duracao) from tabela where fabrica = '+@fabrica+'
and turno IN ('+@turnos+'))'
```

Mas ainda não entendi como fazer para colocar o resultado dessa `@query` na variavel `@tjt`.

Comment: Porque você não faz o select dentro do do `in ()`? por exemplo `...in (select coluna from ..)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a `SP_EXECUTESQL` com um parâmetro `OUTPUT` para obter o resultado desejado:

```
DECLARE @tjt INT;
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @query = '(select @tjt = sum(duracao) from tabela where fabrica = ' + @fabrica + ' and turno IN (' + @turnos + '))';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query, N'@tjt INT OUT', @tjt OUT;

SELECT @tjt;
```

Comment: Exclui meus comentários anteriores com o intuito de não confundir ninguém. 
Mas o código utilizando a `SP_EXECUTESQL` funcionou perfeitamente. A variável `@tjt` recebeu o valor de `sum(duracao)` como eu precisava. Muito obrigado pela apoio.

Comment: @DaniloAlex tem outra forma de fazer sem precisar executar string. Se você informar na pergunta qual a versão do SQL Server eu posso complementar a resposta